# Sum the value of one column based on the maximum value of another column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need a measure to add the last non blank value from column `SaldoConta` from the table `pcsa` below from each column `conta`.

The criteria to define last non blank is the one with maximum value in column `AnoMes`.

```
conta   ano mes AnoMes  SaldoConta
110 2017    2   201702   112,56   
110 2017    0   201700   112,56   
111 2017    4   201704   70,47   
111 2017    0   201700   78,06   
111 2017    1   201701   70,47   
111 2017    2   201702   70,47   
112 2017    8   201708   100,00   
112 2017    3   201703   242,16   
112 2017    10  201710   100,00   
112 2017    2   201702   200,00   
112 2017    11  201711   100,00   
112 2017    12  201712   100,00   
112 2017    5   201705   240,75   
112 2017    1   201701   200,00   
112 2017    4   201704   242,16   
112 2017    0   201700   100,00   
112 2017    9   201709   200,00   
112 2017    6   201706   683,67   
112 2017    7   201707   200,00   
113 2017    2   201702   72 865,90   
113 2017    0   201700   21 114,37   
113 2017    3   201703   55 572,24   
113 2017    1   201701   39 967,48   
114 2017    11  201711   0,00   
114 2017    0   201700   92,59   
114 2017    8   201708   46,40   
114 2017    7   201707   84,50   
115 2017    0   201700   12,00   
116 2017    0   201700   8,27
```

I've tried a million different DAX expressions but it seems impossible to get what I want.

It should add only the LAST nonblank value in AnoMes, so for `conta` 110, it should be `112,56`.

So, the table above should be:

```
conta   ano mes AnoMes  SaldoConta
110 2017    2   201702   112,56   
111 2017    4   201704   70,47   
112 2017    12  201712   100,00   
113 2017    3   201703   55 572,24   
114 2017    11  201711   0,00   
115 2017    0   201700   12,00   
116 2017    0   201700   8,27
```

Comment: Can you give at least a couple rows of the output you expect?

Comment: Please see my edit above, thanks!

Comment: By last, you mean the maximum AnoMes for each conta?

Comment: @Degan yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `conta` as the rows in a matrix or table visual, then you can define `Last SaldoConta` as follows:

```
= SUMX(FILTER(pcsa, pcsa[AnoMes] = MAX(pcsa[AnoMes])), pcsa[SaldoConta])
```

[image: Matrix Visual]

If you don't have the filter context for `conta` or you need it to subtotal correctly, then you need to do a bit more work, but the idea is the same.

```
Last SaldoConta = 
    VAR Summary = SUMMARIZE(pcsa,
                      pcsa[conta],
                      "LastSaldoConta",
                      SUMX(
                          FILTER(pcsa, pcsa[AnoMes] = MAX(pcsa[AnoMes])),
                          pcsa[SaldoConta]))
    RETURN SUMX(Summary, [LastSaldoConta])
```

Inside the `SUMMARIZE` we're creating the filter context for each distinct `conta` value and calculate the last `SaldoConta`. Then we sum all of those up.

Comment: That won't do, because it will fetch the absolute maximum of column "AnoMes", therefore returning 100 (the 3rd row of my second table above).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I matched your output exactly. Are you trying to create a calculated column rather than a measure?

Comment: No, I need a measure. The issue is I don't have 'conta' in a visual, therefore no row context. So, your measure in a card, for example, returns 100 because it gets the absolute maximum of "AnoMes" and I need the rows of the maximum "AnoMes" of each 'conta'.

Comment: That works, thank you! What if I need to add extra filters to the 'pcsa' table? For exemple, to include only the 'conta' values that start with 11 or 'ColumnA' = "Xpto"? Do I need to include these columns in the Summary table? I'll ask another question.

Comment: I don't think so. The summary is still evaluated inside whatever filter context you have. This is why it works not just for the total, but for each `conta` in the matrix visual (the summary just returns a one-row table in that context).